# xelatex+bibtex ignores my \bibstyle definition

Tags: bibtex, xetex

Here is the relevant part of the preamble:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibstyle{huszak}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

I have a huszak.bst file in the same directory as the document.

I compile the document like this:

```
xelatex doc.tex
bibtex doc
xelatex doc.tex
```

bibtex's output is:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: doc.aux
The style file: biblatex.bst
Database file #1: doc-blx.bib
Database file #2: doc.bib.bib
Biblatex version: 0.8i
```

It uses biblatex.bst as the style. I can set anything for \bibstyle, no error will be generated. It completely ignores it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html). All formatting of your bibliography will be done by that package using LaTeX syntax. The `bibtex`-binary is only used for sorting your entries.

Answer (score 2):

biblatex always use only biblatex.bst. Styles are set through options style, bibstyle and citestyle which loads bbx and cbx-files which contain the definitions. (\bibstyle isn't the correct command anyway, it should be \bibliographystyle).